# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier within bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, callback, bookmarklet

I am trying to inject jquery into a page for use in a bookmarklet. I'm having some trouble with the syntax of the callback as I am getting the following error when I run it:

***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier***

The code is below. The error shown in the console looks like its happening near where I call the createScript function. Its a little hard to tell because the code is all smushed. When I paste into JSLint it shows this message:

***Expected ';' and instead saw 'createScript'.***

Code:

```
(function() {  
  console.log("Starting....");
  var createScript = function (url,callback) {
    /* Insert Datatables */                  
    var script_set = document.createElement("script");
    script_set.setAttribute("src", url);
    script_set.addEventListener("load", callback);
    document.body.appendChild(script_set);
  }
  
  createScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", function () {
    console.log("jquery loaded....");
  });
}
)();
```

***UPDATE***

I got it working by making the following change to the top. Just not sure why the error.

Working code:

```
(function() {
  console.log("Starting....");

  function createScript(url, callback) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = url;
      script.async = false;
      script.onload = callback;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
  
  createScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", function () {
    console.log("jquery loaded....");
    console.log("jquery version = "+ $().jquery);
  }
              );
}
)();
```

If anyone knows why I got an error with the top code I would appreciate it to better my understanding of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your bookmarklet is smushed into one line, a missing semicolon between an assignment with a function expression (`var createScript = function (url,callback) {/*...*/}`) and a function call with an identifier (`createScript(/*...*/);`) creates an illegal syntax sequence.

A short example with the same reproducible error and a fixed variant:

```js
const func = function (){} console.log(1);
```

```js
const func = function (){}; console.log(1);
```